# contextmenu (right button click) highstock graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, graphics, highcharts

I need right button click (contextmenu) support for highstock.

I found exactly what i need but only for highchart

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/c42Ms/][1]
```

And can't find same thing for highstock

Please help.

Comment: I changed the jsfiddle to use `<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>` and it worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks i just used old version of highstock. Now it works fine for me

Comment: Reverted the latest edit. While it's a good idea to put the code in instead of a link, there is no evidence to suggest that the editor or poster is licensed to re-post that code here.